# Can´t get data from website using PHP and DOM

Tags: php, dom

I´m trying to get data from this website: https://www.pontoslivelo.com.br/compreepontue/magazineluiza

The data I´m trying to get is this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIsN9.png)

Here´s the code I have so far:

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();

$html->load_file('https://www.pontoslivelo.com.br/compreepontue/magazineluiza');

foreach ($html->find('div[class=pontos-1]') as $div) {
    echo $div->plaintext . "<br>";
}
```

Nothing is returned.

The `$html->find('div[class=pontos-1]')` wasn´t suppose to get all the div from the code? Why can´t he find the one with class=pontos-1?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1011527)

Comment: The element you want to get is dynamically loaded into the document with javascript.

Comment: Is there a way to get this element, since he is dynamically loaded?

Comment: You would need to fully load the page in a browser (or headless browser like PhantomJS) to get any dynamically loaded content. This is really a web-scraping question.

Answer (score -1):

Download and include [Simple HTML DOM](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/) first in your PHP File.

Here is your required code

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('https://www.pontoslivelo.com.br/compreepontue/magazineluiza');

foreach($html->find('div[class=pontos-1]') as $element){
    echo $element->innertext . '<br>';
}
```